# conda install doesn't work in virtualenv created in conda

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda, conda

I create a virtualenv using conda, and install new python packages under this env as following.

```
conda create --name env_2
source activate env_2
conda install biopython

ls ~/anaconda/envs/env_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Bio/  # biopython is installed correctly
```

But I still can not use Bio. Do I miss anything ?

```
>>> import Bio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'Bio'
>>>
```

Comment: Did you start the `python/ipython` in the same terminal tab where you did `source activate env_2` ?

Comment: There's really not enough information here for me to tell exactly what's going on.  I can help though if you provide full terminal session input/output and `conda info` in a github issue at https://github.com/conda/conda.

Answer (score 3):

By default, `conda create --name env_2` will install only `activate`, `deactivate` and `conda` packages in environment, there will be no interpreter installed:

```
$ ls miniconda3/envs/env_2/bin/
activate   conda      deactivate
```

If you want python interpreter be installed you have 3 options:

1. Provide python as a package to install in environment:

   ```
   $ conda create --name env_2 python
   ```
2. Install python as package after creating an env:

   ```
   $ source activate env_2
   (env_2)$ conda install python
   ```
3. Add `python` to the list of default packages ([documentation](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/config.html#always-add-packages-by-default-create-default-packages)):

   ```
   $ cat ~/.condarc
   create_default_packages:
     - python
   ```

**Edit 1:**

Added information from comments.

Comment: do you mean I can not install packages after virtualenv created ? it doesn't make sense

Comment: Well, this is conda environment, not virtualenv one. It works in a bit different way. You can install python explicitly `conda install python` after activating the environment.

Comment: You can also specify list of default packages (in `~/.condarc`'s
 `create_default_packages` section) to be installed in new environments. Conda docs: [Always add packages by default](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/config.html#always-add-packages-by-default-create-default-packages)